# Java combobox shall only popup if a button is pressed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jcombobox

I have a question regarding the popup of a java combobox.

I need to control the popup of a combobox with a java button.

That means I click once on the button, the combobox popup is shown.
If I click again on the button the combobox popup is hidden.

So far this works.

My problem is to avoid the following behavior:

I click on the button, the combobox popup is shown.
Then if I click somwhere else, for example on the border of my frame or an other button or something else the popup of my combobox is also hidden.

I would be happy if somebody can give me a hint how to do this. The combox popup shall only react on the button click (on nothing else).

Greetings and thanks in advance,
Steffen

Answer (score 0):

That is how popups are designed to work.  How does your user click on items behind the popup? Are you really going to require them to click on a button first to hide the popup?

Not seeing all your GUI makes it difficult to determine an alternate suggestion but you might be better off using a `JList` that you expand or contract the preferred size of.

Comment: Yes, you are right, normally a jcombobox should not behave like this, but in my special case I need to simulate the hmi of a device. So as I understood you right there is no easy way to manipulate the jcombox like I need it? I will try it with Jlist. Thanks, Steffen